# Get logged in user in Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to get logged in username in Web Api but unable to do so. Below is my problem -

- I have a Web App developed using AngularJS and Windows authentication is enabled on it.
- I have a API which the Web App calls to get the data.
- API application is configured to use basic authentication so I need to pass logged in username whenever I call any API method.
- The problem is, I can't find a way to get the logged in username and pass it in the request header as I don't have any control over it.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers

Comment: Are you on core, owin?

Comment: @Marcus No if you mean .net core

Comment: The user doesn't have any kind of authentication cookie or anything to identify the user? So, in your controller, what does this code return? `var user = this.User.Identity.Name;`

Comment: No there is no cookie because it is an Angular application and I can't get user to to add auth cookie against. `Identity` returns `null`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh My question has nothing to do with `MessageHandler`